# c++ static initialization of vector of boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, vector, static

```
class IIntro
{
public:
  explicit IIntro(Sprite* _parent = null, IPrize* _prizeImpl = null);
  virtual ~IIntro() {}

  virtual void Play(bool _play = true) = 0;
  static void CreatStateAnims(Sprite* _parent);

protected:

  static typedef boost::shared_ptr<AnimSprite> SPAS;
  static std::vector<SPAS> introAnims;  

};
```

I am getting the "undefined reference to `IIntro::introAnims'" compler error.
How to inititalize

```
static typedef boost::shared_ptr<AnimSprite> SPAS;
static std::vector<SPAS> introAnims;
```

variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since C++11, you can use `using` to create an alias, as well. Might alleviate some confusion.

`using SPAS = boost::shared_ptr<AnimSprite>`

Though I guess since you're using boost::shared_ptr, you probably aren't using C++11 anyways /shrug

Answer (score 3):

You've declared the variable, but not defined it. You need to add the definition to a source file:

```
std::vector<IIntro::SPAS> IIntro::introAnims;
```

Note that `SPAS` is a type, not a variable, so that doesn't need a definition. You do need to remove `static` from its declaration, though; that only makes sense for variables and functions, not types.

Comment: wow, that was really quick. It is working, really appreciated for your help.